# Relationship between Bundle Identifier in Info.plist and App ID and iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, itunes, app-store-connect

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to get my app on iTunes connect with the app loader. I think the problem is the connections between the ID's, and how they all need to match up. Could someone please explain this too me?

My situation -

Bundle Identifier in Info.plist `com.<domain>.<appname>`

Distribution Provisioning Profiles App ID in iOS Provisioning Profile `<10 digit 'bundle seed'>.com.<domain>.<appname>`

'Bundle ID' produced in iTunes Connect `com.<domain>.<appname>`

Is this all correct?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. They are right